# Getting all other columns based on a value Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have the following df:

```
>  Name   A     B     C     D   
   John   Nan   1     2     Nan   
   Mike   2     Nan   Nan   Nan   
   Fred   Nan   5     6     7    
   Ana    3     Nan   3     2   
   Fran   2     Nan   1     1
```

What I want to do is sorting some columns so, I what everyone who has only column A filled (in this case, Mike):

```
> df_1 = df[(df['A'] > 0)&(~(df['A'] == 0))]
```

or I want only two columns filled (in this case, none):

```
df_1 = df[(df['A','B'] > 0)&(~(df['A','B'] == 0))]
```

I am really strugling with this.

tks

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### isnull + all

Your syntax is incorrect. You can use [`pd.DataFrame.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html):

```
mask1 = df['A'] > 0
mask2 = df[['B', 'C', 'D']].isnull().all(1)

df_1 = df_1[mask1 & mask2]
```

Similarly, for your second query:

```
mask1 = (df[['A', 'B']] > 0).all(1)
mask2 = df[['C', 'D']].isnull().all(1)

df_1 = df_1[mask1 & mask2]
```

This assumes you wish to filter explicitly for values greater than 0 in `mask1`. If any non-null number suffices, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html).

Don't be afraid to split your masks across multiple lines in this way. It will make your code clearer and easier to manage.

#### pipe + isnull + all

More generically, you can write a function to calculate and apply your Boolean series mask:

```
def masker(df, cols_required):

    """ Supply list cols_required. These must be > 0; others null. """

    mask1 = (df[cols_required] > 0).all(1)
    mask2 = df[df.columns.difference(cols_required)].isnull().all(1)
    return df[mask1 & mask2]

df = df.pipe(masker, cols_required=['A', 'B'])
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Just to make the code easier. Let´s say I have 1.000 columns, must I always all the columns for the NOT variable?

Comment: You can make it a bit easier. For example, `list('CDEFG')` works as well as `['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']`. Or use `df.columns[i: j]` where `i` and `j` are integer indexers. Or use `df.columns.difference(['A', 'B'])` for all columns except `A` and `B`.